# Tab bar and Navigation controller cannot see anymore in the view controller

Tags: php, xcode, swift3, xcode8

this is for my login view controller to home view controller problem. Supposed to be, once i've logged in, i will go to the view controller where i can see my navigation controller above and may tab controller below. However, i can't see anymore the two controllers in my home view controller. I made a code by the way that once the user logged in, the app will be able to get the user's user id from the database(PHP, MySQLi) and then throw the value of user id to the home VC. I Successfully throw the value from the login to home VC but in return, i can't see my navigation and tab bar controller anymore. here's my code for you to check:

```
//once the user click the login button
DispatchQueue.main.async()
{
   //getting the user id of the user
   let getNum = responseString
   let getBorrowNum = getNum
   self.borrowerNum.text = getBorrowNum! as String

   //going to home view controller
   if self.borrowerNum.text != nil
   {   
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let vc : Home = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainHome") as! Home
     vc.teststring = responseString
     self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    print("Login Success")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainHome") as! Home
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc)
```